# How to open keyboard in Wine app?

Tags: keyboard, input-methods, emulators, text-input, text-editor

I would like to use Notepad++ on Android, if possible. The only thing I found was [this app](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/android), which, unlike the regular Wine, seems to emulate an entire Windows system. The only problem: I can't enter text. Surely I could connect a Bluetooth keyboard, but at that point I might as well take a laptop with me. I've also tried simulating a press of the Alt key using the app "XPosed Edge", but that doesn't open the keyboard, unlike in some other situations. Even when I let XPosed Edge enter a preset text, it does not appear in the console window in Wine.

So how do I enter text in this app? Alternatively, is there a different way to get Notepad++ running on Android (or is there a proper app with all of its features)?

Comment: [This thread](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=30082&p=114118&hilit=Keyboard#p114118) suggests installing extra software just to open the keyboard, which I not only find strange, but I also doubt that it works, since entering text with XPosed Edge didn't work.

Comment: Not related to question, but notepadqq is a linux alternative and for android try DroidEdit

Comment: Not a full replacement, but "QuickEdit" has syntax highlighting, persistent state, regex search+replace, optional word wrap, undo/redo, autocomplete, line numbers, style options, autosave, …: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.edit